# ASPX + Angular, retrieve or store UserID at client?

Tags: angularjs, security, webforms

A big ASPX (webform) project, introducing AngularJS to client side. This is a very sophisticated app but content is UserID-based. Currently back-end .aspx.cs has a base class contains UserID for each session. So it's available for every request and HTML content will be generated easily at the back end. 
With Angular, we certainly can do:

```
  $(document).ready(function) { 
    // Step 1. right away go back to server ask what's my UserID.
    // Step 2. 2nd trip to provide UserID to server for data for UI.
  }
```

It looks really silly. Can I have .aspx.cs to store UserID say in a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="myUserID" value="123"/>
```

Angular then grabs it to avoid step 1?

My concern is security. Assuming current webform project is sound and safe. Is it safe to do that or there is a better way?

Comment: It is as safe as your application is...

Comment: Wasn't thinking, .aspx.cs should lay the sessionID instead of explicit UserID.

Answer (score 0):

After some thoughts, believe it should lay down the sessionID plus anti-CRSF if possible. So, step 1 is no need but step 2 will submit sessionID value to server.